# How to disable future date in ajax calendarextender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, calendarextender

I have an user control in AJAX for the date calendar and I want to disable the future dates in the Calendar. I have tried to do it by using the Maximum Value property but that doesn't disables the control.

Any suggestions or help?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="usrCtrlDatePicker.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_usrCtrlDatePicker" %>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="height:18px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; height:16px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEntry" runat="server" Width="75px" MaxLength="1" style="text-align:justify"/>
            <img alt="" id="btnShowCalendar" runat="server" src="../images/calendar.gif" style="margin-left:-4px; margin-bottom:-3px; height:17px; width:17px;" />
            <ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeDateEntry" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="txtDateEntry"
                Mask="99/99/9999"
                MessageValidatorTip="false"
                CultureName="en-US"
                OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
                OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
                MaskType="Date"
                ErrorTooltipEnabled="false"   />
            <ajax:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevDateEntry"  runat="server" ControlExtender="meeDateEntry" ControlToValidate="txtDateEntry" Display="Dynamic" EmptyValueBlurredText="*" EmptyValueMessage="Date is required" InvalidValueBlurredMessage="*" InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid" IsValidEmpty="false" MaximumValueBlurredMessage="sjdfhsdfh" MaximumValueMessage="Maximum Value Exceeded." TooltipMessage="" ValidationExpression="(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" ValidationGroup="" />
             <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ceDateEntry" runat="server"
                Format="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                TargetControlID="txtDateEntry" 
                PopupButtonID="btnShowCalendar" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If future date disable is required then following link can help

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Future-Dates-in-ASPNet-AJAX-Calendar-Extender-Control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnClientDateSelectionChanged event. Refer [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1844678.aspx?Disable%20future%20date%20in%20Ajax%20CalendarExtender).

Comment: Thank you Ashokd for your reply! But the place where OnClientDateSelectionChanged is used in the link doesn't talk about disabling the future date.

Comment: There is checkDate function getting called on this event which restricts date selection

Comment: I don't want to restrict the any date selection but want to disable the future dates.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to disable the future dates in the Asp.net ajax calendar extender

By setting the **EndDate** property of calendar extender you can achieve this required functionality or by using css class. css class technique is given below in the second link

For reference please check the following links, In the second link it uses css class to disable future dates.

[Disable Future and Past Date](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/disable-future-and-past-date-of-ajax-calendar-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

[Disable Future Dates in ASP.Net AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Future-Dates-in-ASPNet-AJAX-Calendar-Extender-Control.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tanzeel! But I am not using Asp.net calendar extender, I am using  Ajax CalendarExtender and EndDate Property is not present for this control. Also, I already came across both the links you sent but they were not useful.

Comment: @Nalini yes you are using ajax calendarextender from asp.net ajax control toolkit.  did you try this code ceDateEntry.EndDate. if this is not helpful please let me know which version of ajax controls you are using.

Comment: Yes, I don't have EndDate property for my Ajax calendarextender. I am using 1.0.10618.0 version